# Node.js and web-socket-js simple client server not opening

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ports

My server.js seems to be correct..

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "mysite.com");
console.log('Server running at mysite.com:1337/');
```

The meat of my client is below.

```
function init() {

  // Connect to Web Socket.
  // Change host/port here to your own Web Socket server.
  ws = new WebSocket("ws://mysite.com:1337");

  // Set event handlers.
  ws.onopen = function() {
    output("onopen");
  };

}
```

If I go to http://www.mysite.com:1337 I correctly receive Hello World!  However, when I try to connect using my client, and debug in Fire bug, I get the following output.

```
[WebSocket] connected
[WebSocket] request header: GET / HTTP/1.1 Upgrade: WebSocket Connection: Upgrade Host: mysite.com:1337 Origin: http://www.mysite.com Cookie: Sec-WebSocket-Key1: 115 17 p^!x-93 IERc16 7 Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 1 75 7Z i `. 8u $l031 4j9
[WebSocket] sent key3: ±Ôñ<g
[WebSocket] closed
```

And the WebSocket is automatically closed before I have any chance to do anything.  Can anyone please shed some light on the error I am receiving and what do you think I should do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created a node.js HTTP server but you are trying to connect to it as a WebSockets server. The WebSockets protocol is not plain sockets and it is not plain HTTP request. WebSockets have an HTTP like handshake but after that you have a full-duplex connection (like sockets and unlike HTTP) that has a small amount of message framing (unlike plain sockets).

Try using [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) or [node-websocket-server](https://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server) if you want to create a node.js WebSockets server. On the other hand if you are wanting to connect from Javascript to a regular HTTP server then use one of the great Javascript libraries with AJAX support such as [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).